# constraints on the rows and columns of a matrix

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

I would like to create a mxn matrix of random values in MATLAB. The constraints are that each element of a column must be lower than or equal to a fix constant  and each row must sum to one. 
I've just coded for this matrix by "for" and "while" scripts which is trapped in the loop. May you please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the problem with your code? why aren't you posting it and asking a specific question?

Comment: I guess, you should add your coding to get better help ...

Comment: Is that `" fix constant "` different for different columns?